# @ejb throws NullPointerException in rest service

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, nullpointerexception, ejb

I have ejb class:

```
@Stateless
public class WholesaleEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "wholesale")
    EntityManager entityManager; 

    public void createClient(Clients client) {
        System.out.println("Creating car!");
        entityManager.persist(client);
    }

}
```

I try to inject it in REST class:

```
@Stateless
@Path("wholesale")
public class WholesaleREST implements WholesaleInterface {

    @EJB
    private WholesaleEJB bean;

    @Override
    @POST
    @Path("/create")
    public String createClient(InputStream is) {
        Clients clients = JAXB.unmarshal(is, Clients.class);
        bean.createClient(clients);                  //here is nullpointer
        return "car created!";
    }
}
```

Rest interface:

```
@Local
public interface WholesaleInterface {
    public abstract String createClient(InputStream is);

}
```

I read in other posts that you have to inject `@EJB` in bean, so I added `@Stateless` to my rest service class. I also read that beans should have interfaces so I added Interfaces. Program Still throws `NullPointerException` in rest class in line that I commented. I didn't find similar problem in other posts, so I ask question myself. I believe that error is easy and somebody smarter than me will find it in a minute. I spent whole day looking for it. Please help. Thank you for your time.

Edit: Removed EjbInterface and mappedName attribute like I was advised in comments.

Comment: I think you don't need that interface in the first place, I never used one. Better try without to reduce potential errors...

Comment: I deleted EjbInterface, still NullpointerException.

Comment: I expected that.... but it might be easier to debug then!

Comment: You could 1. edit your post to eliminate the interface usage, 2. check your configuration to see if something general is wrong! I don't see any other reason why the @EJB annotation shouldn't work. Yet I'm not familiar with that "mappedName" attribute, so I don't know if that's wrong. Check all logs carefully!

Comment: I did as you suggested, I really tried a lot of things and I run out of ideas. I gave up and I need help.

Comment: Do you still use that WholesaleInterface? By using it, you use "@Stateless" and "@Local" at the same time (I think...) - and I'm not sure if that would work! I would suggest eliminating that WholesaleInterface, too, you can add it later, after you've had some success with it.

Comment: I removed WholesaleInterfalce as well. Still Nullpointer I don't know whats happenning I do everything like in tutorials in the internet.

Comment: What about changing @Path("wholesale") to @Path("/wholesale")? Plus adding an @ApplicationPath("/xy") on class level.

Comment: It didn't change anything.

Comment: Sorry that I can't help any better! Sometimes the devil is in the detail and hard to find. But I always found that in the end the computer was right. ;-)  Cheers!

Comment: Can you specify your application server, and version?